# required value on persistentVolumeClaim

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

hy folks

i made the yaml files to deploy my application and now i working with helm to deploy it automatically.However although all of my conf files dor kubernetes worked. i've a problem with helm and `PVC`. 
i ve checked on internet and i dont find where is my mistake :(

**pvc-helm.yaml**

```
{{- if .Values.persistence.enabled }}
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: {{ .Values.persistence.name }}
  namespace: {{ .Values.persistence.namespace }}
  spec:
    accessModes:
    - {{ .Values.persistence.accessModes | quote }}
    resources:
      requests:
        storage: {{ .Values.persistence.size | quote }}
{{- end }}
```

**values.yaml**

```
persistence:
  enabled: true
  name: ds-pvc
  namespace: ds-svc
  storageClassName: standard
  storageClass: standard
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  size: 20Mi
```

when i run the command `helm install cas/ --tls` i get the error below

> Error: release brawny-olm failed: PersistentVolumeClaim "ds-pvc" is
>   invalid: [spec.accessModes: Required value: at least 1 access mode is
>   required, spec.resources[storage]: Required value]

Do i've to set as well a `PersistentVolume` ?

Answer (score 1):

There are two issues in your helm chart:

**1.** `spec` level shouldn't be below `metadata` level. It has no relations to `metadata`, so `spec` is on the same level as `metadata`.

**2.** Value `persistence.accessModes` should be defined as a string, not as a list.

The correct files are:

**pvc-helm.yaml**

```
{{- if .Values.persistence.enabled }}
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: {{ .Values.persistence.name }}
  namespace: {{ .Values.persistence.namespace }}
spec:
  accessModes:
  - {{ .Values.persistence.accessModes | quote }}
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: {{ .Values.persistence.size | quote }}
{{- end }}
```

**values.yaml**

```
persistence:
  enabled: true
  name: ds-pvc
  namespace: default
  storageClassName: standard
  storageClass: standard
  accessModes: ReadWriteOnce
  size: 20Mi
```

Comment: thank for your help .i've one more question in helm why sometimes we use `quote ` as i did before for  `storage: {{ .Values.persistence.size | quote }}`. i 've seen that on github repositories

Comment: You can find an answer to your additional question [here](https://github.com/helm/helm/blob/master/docs/charts_tips_and_tricks.md#chart-development-tips-and-tricks)

Comment: @morla that's true. When we are working with `string` it is safer to use `quote` on that. I've corrected my answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have optional values you should check if they have been defined

```
spec:
  {{- if .Values.persistence.accessModes }}
  accessModes:
  - {{ .Values.persistence.accessModes | quote }}
  {{- end }}
```

another option is define a default value on the `values.yaml` file